# How can I sort a mix of numeric and alphabetic characters?

Tags: sort

How can I sort input such as this using the `sort` command? I would like the numbers to be sorted numerically before the letters.

```
10
11
12
1
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
2
22
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
X
Y
```

Comment: Sort them how, exactly? That seems like a completely arbitrary sort order. And those aren't numbers. Also, you forgot chrM. Please [edit] your question and clarify. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: [No attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and [unclear what you're asking](https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion). Please add your desired output and what you tried to obtain it.

Comment: To the other commenters: He wants to sort these numbers numerically, so a 2 would come before 15, if it were alphabetically 2 would come after 15, because 2 comes after 1.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

As @terdon noticed, the inclusion of `X` and `Y` and the fact that the numbers run from 1 to 22 identifies this as a possible list of human chromosomes (which is why he says that chromosome `M` (mitochondrial) may be missing).

To sort a list of numbers, one would usually use `sort -n`:

```
$ sort -n -o list.sorted list
```

where `list` is the unsorted list, and `list.sorted` will be the resulting sorted list.

With `-n`, `sort` will perform a numerical sort on its input.  However, since some of the input is not numerical, the result is probably not the intended; `X` and `Y` will appear first in the sorted list, not last (the sex chromosomes are usually listed after chromosome 22).

However, if you use `sort -V` (for "version sorting"), you will actually get what you want:

```
$ sort -V -o list.sorted list
$ cat list.sorted
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
X
Y
```

This will probably still not work if you do add `M` as that would be sorted before `X` and not at the end (which I believe is how it's usually presented).

Comment: Oh, so the list of values presented in the question is the set to be sorted rather then the intended result of some (apparently arbitrary) sorting?

Comment: @roaima That is how I interpret it. And if it's chromosomes, they are most likely to be sorted numerically, and then `X` followed by `Y`.

Comment: Thanks. It threw me completely; i didn't expect the list to be the raw set, but rather the sorted set. I've tweaked the language in the question a little to try and help clarify that.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean they should sort in the 1..22, X, Y, M order, then you can translate those X, Y, M to numbers before sorting and back after sorting:

```
sed 's/X/23/;s/Y/24/;s/M/25/' < file | sort -n | sed 's/23/X/;s/24/Y/;s/25/M/'
```

If those numbers are in a `zsh` array, you can apply an arbitrary sort  order using this hack:

```
k=({1..22} X Y M) v=({01..25})
typeset -A rank=(${k:^v})

unsorted=(22 Y 5 X M 13)
sorted=(/(e'{reply=($unsorted)}'oe'{REPLY=$rank[$REPLY]}'))
```

Or if the members of `$unsorted` are unique, use array intersection:

```
all=({1..22} X Y M)
unsorted=(22 Y 5 X M 13)
sorted=(${all:*unsorted})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
cat number.txt|sort -n
```

Comment: See my answer as to why this will probably not generate the correct result. Also, `cat` is totally unnecessary here.